# How would I go about building a slider where the items are lowered opacity except for the one the user was one currently?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slider

[Image of what I'm thinking for the slider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lw7C9.jpg)

My idea for the slider is to have 3 items visible at all times. The left and right most ones would have a lowered opacity, while the one the user is currently on (the centered one) would be full opacity and given a drop shadow.

I know how to go about creating a slider, so it slides through all the items, however, I'm not sure how to set it so once the item is centered it would no longer have an opacity and would gain a drop shadow.

Comment: Sounds like you could just do that with css. whatever your slider does to move slides, apply a class to the current/active slide and use `opacity` and `box-shadow` https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/ZydPrP is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

```css
.outer {
  height: 80px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slider {
  position: relative;
  left: -40%;
  width: calc(180%);
}

.slider>div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left;
  line-height: 30px;
  width: 30%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px 0px;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

.slider>div {
  opacity: 0.6;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.slider .centered {
  opacity: 1;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="outer">
  <div class="slider">
    <div>left visible content</div>
    <div class="centered">center content</div>
    <div>right visible content</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I believe that's probably what you're looking for. If you have the slider already and can identify the center one with a class then it's just css.

Comment: Thank you, but how would I move the class of centered to the next element when the user uses the slider? That's my biggest dilemma, is that possible with CSS or should I use JavaScript for that?

Comment: $(".slider div:not(.centered)").on("click", function(ev){ 
  $(".centered").removeClass("centered");
  this.addClass("centered");
});